# When dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c(DocuSign Status) record will be created in SalesForce?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have created a custom filed in dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c sObject it is getting populated when I use JavaScript button on page layout. Now, I want to populate this custom field in dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c record after Envelope has been sent(which I think creates dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c record)through Apex(using SOAP API). I tried with populating custom field and respective value while preparing Envelop by using CustomFiled.

I am using CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates method to prepare and send envelop.